# How to prevent users with Paypal subscription having trial to cancel and have another trial period

Tags: paypal

I have a SaaS with Paypal subscription.
In Paypal we can have a trial period as a part of the plan, which is managed by Paypal.

Is there any pattern to organize account deletion and subscription cancelation? I see some options?

1. Users can cancel subscription, but if they want to make a new subscription - they will get a new trial since it's a new subscription. I could get another plan without trial for this, but can't they substitute plan ID with the one with trial with some HTML knowledge?
2. Subscription cancelation can only be done together with account deletion. User can suspend subscription if he doesn't want to delete the account. Suspension is not exactly like cancelation, looks incomplete, like you may pay accidentally at some point.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, a plan_id on the client side can be changed. You could conceivably create the subscription using the create subscription API call and fetch the ID of the created subscription instead, with a pattern similar to https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server
2. Subscriptions can always be cancelled in the payer's PayPal account.

Whatever solution you decide on, register for the webhook PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED and build you logic using that. For reconciliation, add a `custom_id` when the subscription is created; this can essentially be your own user ID or whatever other unique identifier you want.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding 1 - yeap, that's how I'm doing it. But this all is done client side and user can substitute plan_id in the API - that's my concern. However now I think that I could just get subscription info and compare plan ID with expected plan ID afterwards. And if it doesn't match - cancel subscription and say something went wrong. A bit of a hustle but not that much.

As for webhook - thanks for mentioning that, definitely a thing I need to introduce at least as a backup if user refreshes the page at the wrong time.